# Is there a (cultural, religious etc?) reason, why equus and aequus are nearly homophones?

Tags: etymology

> Equus:
>
> (Classical) IPA(key): /ˈe.kʷus/, [ˈɛ.kʷʊs]

---

> Aequus:
>
> (Classical) IPA(key): /ˈae̯.kʷus/, [ˈae̯.kʷʊs]

Is this similarity coincidental or do they have a common origin? Are there any specific reasons why the two words are so similar-sounding - some cultural reason, myth, belief, tradition of respect towards horses or the like?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to http://starling.rinet.ru, they come from different [Proto Indo-European roots](http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/response.cgi?root=config&morpho=0&basename=%5Cdata%5Cie%5Cpiet&first=1&off=&text_proto=&method_proto=substring&ic_proto=on&text_meaning=&method_meaning=substring&ic_meaning=on&text_hitt=&method_hitt=substring&ic_hitt=on&text_tokh=&method_tokh=substring&ic_tokh=on&text_ind=&method_ind=substring&ic_ind=on&text_avest=&method_avest=substring&ic_avest=on&text_iran=&method_iran=substring&ic_iran=on&text_arm=&method_arm=substring&ic_arm=on&text_greek=&method_greek=substring&ic_greek=on&text_slav=&method_slav=substring&ic_slav=on&text_balt=&method_balt=substring&ic_balt=on&text_germ=&method_germ=substring&ic_germ=on&text_lat=equus&method_lat=substring&ic_lat=on&text_ital=&method_ital=substring&ic_ital=on&text_celt=&method_celt=substring&ic_celt=on&text_alb=&method_alb=substring&ic_alb=on&text_rusmean=&method_rusmean=substring&ic_rusmean=on&text_refer=&method_refer=substring&ic_refer=on&text_comment=&method_comment=substring&ic_comment=on&text_any=&method_any=substring&sort=proto&ic_any=on). The database is based in the [Indo-European Etymological Dictionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indo-European_Etymological_Dictionary) project.

- *aequus* would come from *aikʷ-, meaning flat and also present in Baltic languages such as Lithuanian.
- *equus* would come from *ek'w-, meaning *horse*, properly. Hippos comes from the same root.

I'm no Proto-IE expert, but apparently these are regular transformations, and it is nothing but a coincidence (or, at most, an example of *convergent evolution*).

*Caveat*: since Proto-IE was never written, all we have is a theoretical reconstruction, mostly agreed by scholars (and thus reliable enough for modern-day purposes). That is why roots always start with an asterisk (*): they aren't properly attested. Maybe if we travelled back in time we'd be surprised.

Comment: And, that doesn't rule out a former common origin: the horse as a flat surface to sit on? Actually Spanish *caballo* (horse) comes from a Medieval Latin root meaning *table* (but that is no more than linguistics-fiction)

Comment: Not sure where you got that fact about *caballo*: what about Latin [caballus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcaballus1)? Also, out of curiosity, it baffles me (with no formal linguistics training) how *hippos* could come from **ek'w*, as you mention. Any thoughts?

Comment: @brianpck Actually my memory betrayed me. Shall I delete the comment? However there is the fact that PIE rooting does not rule out a previous common origin. Regarding the development of *hippos*, sound changes may be surprising. See the last one in [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Greek_language#Proto-Greek_changes) (*merging sequences of velar + ...*)

Comment: @Rafael: while it doesn't rule out a previous common origin, we won't know it without a time engine, for sure. That's beyond the domain of viable theoretical reconstruction. That's guessing, and not even particularly informed guessing.

Comment: @SF Sure, that's why I put it that way, and in a comment ;)

Comment: The PIE forms do rule out a common origin, since they don't have a single sound in common (*kʷ is not the same as *k'w).

Comment: @TKR. aequus does not have any generally accepted cognates outside of Italic (the Lithuanian parallel suggested in the “Starling” link is questionable). But this means that we do not know whether it goes back to a form with kʷ or with ḱw, as these would have an identical outcome in Latin. The “horse” word definitely has ḱw (cf Sanskrit aśva-).

Comment: @fdb Good point. Still, even if *aequus* reflects PIE *ḱw, I don't see any obvious PIE morphological process that could relate its ancestor to that of *equus*.

Comment: @TKR. I agree completely.